# Get command-line arguments from spring-boot:run

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, command-line-arguments

Is there any way to input arguments when launching spring-boot application (mvn spring-boot:run) from commandline and then get them in main()?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/07bb33d8ed302d70f44b33ed419cc1a6fe08c9f6/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/AbstractRunMojo.java#L116) of the spring-boot-maven-plugin I found that you need to do:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="arg1,arg2"
```

Another way to get more information about what options the `run` goal of the `spring-boot` plugin supports is to execute the following command:

```
mvn help:describe -Dcmd=spring-boot:run -Ddetail
```

For Spring Boot 2.x, the source is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/68c6860d88b69756ffd0dff76c64e3e29c29ab68/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/AbstractRunMojo.java#L113) and you now need to use `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="args1,args2"`

(edit from april 2021)
For Spring Boot 2.2+, you now need to use `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="args1 args2"`

If you are using Gradle and you want to be able to pass command line arguments to the Gradle `bootRun` task, you first need to configure, for example like so:

```
bootRun {
    if ( project.hasProperty('args') ) {
        args project.args.split('\\s+')
    }
}
```

and run the task using `gradle bootRun -Pargs="arg1 arg2"`

Comment: Quite stupid of them to accept commas over the standard spaces. RTFM Spring:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: With gradle 3.3 the following modification worked for me:

```bootRun {
    // Usage: gradle bootRun -Pargs="arg1 arg2"
    if ( project.hasProperty('args') ) {
        args = (project.args.split("\\s+") as List)
    }
}
```

Comment: @FarrukhNajmi I will check it out and update the answer, thanks

Comment: Starting from Spring Boot 2, you should use `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=`

Comment: Note, this as of now accepted answer is out of date for Spring Boot 2.2 and higher. See the newer answer under this question - the arguments are now separated by a space, not by a comma.

Answer (score 40):

When passing multiple arguments using -Drun.arguments, if the argument in turn has 'comma-separated' values, then only the first value of each argument is used. To avoid this repeat the argument as many times as the number of values.

This is more of a workaround. Not sure if there is an alternative unless the delimiter is different - like '|'.

E.g Issue:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=test,dev"
```

Picks only 'test' profile for the above command.

Workaround:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=test,--spring.profiles.active=dev"
```

Picks both 'dev' & 'test' profiles for the above command.

Comment: Starting from Spring Boot 2, you should use `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=`

Answer (score 27):

**Be aware : The way of passing arguments depends on the `spring-boot` major.minor version.**

**TLDR**

For Spring Boot 1:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="argOne,argTwo"
```

For Spring Boot 2.0 and 2.1:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="argOne,argTwo"
```

(edit from april 2021)
For Spring boot 2.2 and later:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="argOne argTwo"
```

---

1. `spring-boot-maven-plugin` version and the the `Spring Boot` version you use has to be aligned.

According to the Spring Boot major version used (`1` or `2`), the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in the `1`  or the `2` version should indeed be used.
If your `pom.xml` inherits from the `spring-boot-starter-parent` :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>ONE_OR_TWO_VERSION</version>
</parent>
```

In your pom, the version of the plugin used should not even be specified as this plugin dependency is inherited :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>                   
        <configuration>
           ...
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

In case of your `pom.xml` not inheriting from `spring-boot-starter-parent`, don't forget to align the version of `spring-boot-maven-plugin` with the exact version of `spring boot` you want to use.

2. Passing arguments in command line with **spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.X.X**

For one argument :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="argOne"
```

for multiple :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="argOne,argTwo"
```

The [maven plugin page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) documents it :

```
  Name         Type       Since           Description
arguments  |  String[]  |  1.0  | Arguments that should be passed 
                                  to the application. On command line use 
                                  commas to separate multiple arguments.
                                  User property is: run.arguments.
```

3. Passing arguments in command line with **spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.X.X**

For one argument :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="argOne"
```

for multiple :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="argOne,argTwo"
```

I didn't find the plugin documentation for the 2.X.X version that refers to that.
But the `org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo` class of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.M3` plugin refers to this user property:

```
public abstract class AbstractRunMojo extends AbstractDependencyFilterMojo
   ...
   @Parameter(property="spring-boot.run.arguments")
   private String[] arguments;
   ...
   protected RunArguments resolveApplicationArguments(){
     RunArguments runArguments = new RunArguments(this.arguments);
     addActiveProfileArgument(runArguments);
     return runArguments;
   }
   ...
 }
```

4. Hint : as you pass more than one argument, whitespaces between commas are considered.

   mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="argOne,argTwo"

will be interpreted as `["argOne", "argTwo"]`

But this :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="argOne, argTwo"
```

will be interpreted as `["argOne", " argTwo"]`

(edit from march 2021)

Whitespaces are now used as separator for multiple-arguments commands, see the relevant [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20121).

Comment: How do you specify arguments inside of the pom.xml `configuration` section of the plugin? I tried `<arguments><argument>-Dprop=value</argument></arguments>` but it does not pick up the property  value this way.

Comment: @user1902183 use `<arguments><argument>--prop=value</argument></arguments>`

Answer (score 13):

As I checked today, the correct usage for Spring Boot 2.2.5 is:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--arg1=value --arg2=value"
```

Because help says:

> ```
> commandlineArguments
>   User property: spring-boot.run.arguments
>   Arguments from the command line that should be passed to the application.
>   Use spaces to separate multiple arguments and make sure to wrap multiple
>   values between quotes. When specified, takes precedence over arguments.
> ```

Comment: And you can mix unnamed parameters and named arguments like this: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="parameter1 --arg2=value"`. Also probably advisable to quote all parameters in single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot 1 as 2 provide a way to pass multiple profiles as argument and avoid the issue related to the comma used both as separator between the args and the values passed as active profile.

So instead of writing :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.profiles.active=test,--spring.profiles.active=dev
```

use [the Spring Boot Maven `profiles` property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#profiles)  that is a convenience shortcut of `spring.profiles.active` such as the followings :

The Maven user property is different according to the Spring Boot version.

For Spring Boot 1.4+, that is `run.profiles` :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=dev,test
```

For Spring Boot 2, that is `spring-boot.run.profiles` :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev,test
```

From the plugin documentation :

> **profiles**:
>
> The spring profiles to activate. Convenience shortcut of specifying
>   the 'spring.profiles.active' argument. On command line use commas to
>   separate multiple profiles.
>
> Type: java.lang.String[]
>
> Since: 1.3
>
> Required: No
>
> User Property: **spring-boot.run.profiles**

Answer (score 3):

I'm using spring.boot 2.4.2 and i separated the arguments with withe-space and put the values between double quotes.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--param1=value2 --param2=value2"
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you're using Eclipse...

```
| Parameter Name | Value         |
| run.arguments  | "--name=Adam" |
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (`spring-boot v1.4.3.RELEASE`),.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=test,local -Dlogback-debug=true
```

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of spring use **-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=** as shown in the example below

```
spring-boot:run -Djasypt.encryptor.password=temp -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="OU,Grade"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command for a Spring Boot application.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true --config.password=PASSWORD --config.token=s.TOKEN --spring.application.name=ENV --config.server.ip=IP_ADDRESS --spring.profiles.active=ENV --spring.profiles.active.custom=ENV_custom"
```

Bean loading order retrieval

f1f3d6f3-64b8-4fe1-8e50-9747d24557e3

```
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
```