# SpringBoot mvn test arguments

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-3

I create one project with springboot and in my pom.xml I put some arguments to use when run mvn spring-boot:run just like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--DATABASE_IP=localhost</argument>
            <argument>--DATABASE_PORT=5432</argument>
            <argument>--DATABASE=rtdpjlite_test</argument>
            <argument>--DATABASE_USERNAME=user</argument>
            <argument>--DATABASE_PASSWORD="</argument>
        </arguments>
        <jvmArguments>
            -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m         
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

so when I run mvn spring-boot:run he will use this properties in my code, but now I need to run a mvn test, so it's possible to create something like the code above to use when I run the test?

tks

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using de-facto way of configuring spring boot app using [application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpringBoot profiles for this and run something like is you want to specify arguments through command line or you can create profile specific properties files and specify the arguments there

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=production -Drun.arguments="arg1,arg2"
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

[Get command-line arguments from spring-boot:run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316843/get-command-line-arguments-from-spring-bootrun)