# How to run job parameters in spring batch with maven in CLI

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-batch

I have seen several stackoverflow Q&As but none had a job parameter in CLI while using maven.

My parameter is setup like this:

```
@Value("#{jobParameters.getOrDefault('startTimestamp', null)}") Long startTimestamp
@Value("#{jobParameters.getOrDefault('endTimestamp', null)}") Long endTimestamp
```

My maven command is like this:

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring.batch.job.names=myJob -Dspring.profiles.active=default,dev -f pom.xml
```

I am not sure what to add. the following is not working:

```
-Dspring.batch.job.startTimestamp=1667790578000
-Dspring.batch.job.parameters.startTimestamp=1667790578000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to be working.

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=startTimestamp=1667790578000,endTimestamp=1667790578000 -Dspring.batch.job.names=myJob -Dspring.profiles.active=default,dev -f pom.xml
```

found the stackoverflow: [Get command-line arguments from spring-boot:run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316843/get-command-line-arguments-from-spring-bootrun)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to pass job parameters with maven, you can use:

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="param1=value1 param2=value2"`

You can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run-parameters-details-commandlineArguments) the documentation.

Comment: helpful. but not exactly correct. It did help me find the correct answer. so thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped you! Yes, it is valid starting from version 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Job parameters are set through the jobLauncher. For example:

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
    .addLong("startTimestamp", 1667790578000L).toJobParameters();

JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

If you want to send the parameter as a property, you need to use the `@Value` annotation to inject your custom property into the bean that launches the job.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, you can pass job parameters as key/value pairs:

```
java -jar myjob.jar name=foobar startTimestamp=1667790578000
```