# When running spring batch from maven, how do you set job parameters?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-batch

Lets say you run a spring batch program from maven:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.batch.job.names=MyJobNameHere
```

What if I want to send job parameters? How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316843/get-command-line-arguments-from-spring-bootrun), I found you can send parameters into a spring boot application using

```
-Drun.arguments="param1=value1,param2=value2"
```

Example:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.batch.job.names=jobNameHere -Drun.arguments="arg=val,arg2=val2" -f pom.xml
```

When running a Spring Batch, that same technique seems to work.